# Calculating coordinates along a line based on two points on a 2D plane

Tags: linear-algebra

To give you context, I'm trying to animate a character across a screen in a computer program.

I have a 2D plane that's 400px (pixels) by 400px.  The starting point of the character can be anywhere on this canvas.  When a second point is set, I need that character to move towards that destination.

So my question is, **how do I calculate a point in between two points, in any direction?**  Say I'm starting at {100,100}, and the destination is {10,50} and he moves at a rate of 5 pixels per second.  How do I know his exact coordinates on the plane 2 seconds in?

Answer (score 1):

If you want him to move in a straight line from $v_0$ toward $v_1$,  let $\hat{v} = \frac{v_1 - v_0}{||v_1 - v_0||}$.  Then $5\hat{v}$ is your characters velocity .  So *position* = *initial position* + *velocity* * *time*.  You may want the character to move in a curve between the two points though.

The formula above I gave was for vectors.  But remember $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b  \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y  \end{pmatrix} $ if and only if $a = x$ and $b= y$.  Put that together with your vector formula to find out how you should calculate each coordinate (a.k.a. component).

Comment: So does this need to be calculated separately for both x and y coordinates?  As in, I need to calculate *positionX = initial positionX + velocity \* time* **then** *positionY = initial positionY + velocity \* time*?

Comment: See my edits above

Answer (score 1):

OK the first thing to do is to calculate how far your character is going to move while walking between P1 = (100,100) and P2 = (10,50).

```
  Dist = squareroot((X2-X1)*(X2-X1)+(Y2-Y1)*(Y2-Y1)) = Sqrt(90*90+50*50) = sqrt(10600) = 103 (rounded off)
```

Now calculate the time it should take at your characters speed of 5 pix/sec

```
  Totaltime = Dist/speed = 103/5 = 20.6 seconds.
```

Now the easy bit. His X position increases by (X2-X1)/Totaltime each second, and his Y position increases by (Y2-Y1)/TotalTime each second, so X position at time T will be X1+T*(X2-X1)/TotalTime.

```
  X(T) = X1 + T*(X2-X1)/TotalTime = 100 + T*(10-100)/20.6 = 100-4.37*T
  Y(T) = 100 - 2.43*T
```

Note that in this case, because X and Y are getting smaller, the 4.37 and 2.43 are -ve. If the character was moving in a different direction one or both might be positive.

So for your specific question, at 2 seconds the character should be at (91.26, 95.14)